# "Unable to Load App, Server Error" in ExactTarget IMH/MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel

We've spent a few days trying to get SSO/JWT working with an app we're building for HubExchange.

We started by simply setting up the Subscriber Search Node app from https://code.exacttarget.com/api/sample-app-subscriber-search with the credentials the required credentials in App Center (Application Endpoints, Client ID, Client Secret, App Signature, etc). We followed the instructions very carefully.

We're building this on the ET sandbox and we are using https://auth-test.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken by node-fuel in this example to get tokens, because there isn't information about it in request.session. We get a token back and then use that token as the session token when using node-fuel.

My understanding is that when the App loads in IMH, the application login page will receive an encoded JWT, which we then decode using the application signature of the app, but we are not getting this JWT payload from the App.

We have the app running fine on locally but when we load the app in IMH, we get a message "*Unable to Load App, Server Error. We are unable to load the application you requested. Please try again later.*"

I think there is a clue here when tracing the console output from the browser:

```
 Failed to load resource https://pulse.test.exacttarget.com/pubsub/cometd/handshake
 GET https://pulse.test.exacttarget.com/pubsub/cometd/handshake?jsonp=jQuery1710…3A60000%2C%22interval%22%3A0%7D%2C%22id%22%3A%222%22%7D%5D&_=1390473712263  fuel-all.min.js?_=1.5.305:137
 send fuel-all.min.js?_=1.5.305:137
 f.extend.ajax fuel-all.min.js?_=1.5.305:137
 d.jsonpSend imh-all.min.js?_=1.5.305:6
 b.transportSend imh-all.min.js?_=1.5.305:6
 l imh-all.min.js?_=1.5.305:6
 o imh-all.min.js?_=1.5.305:6
 b.send imh-all.min.js?_=1.5.305:6
 bb imh-all.min.js?_=1.5.305:6
 bl imh-all.min.js?_=1.5.305:6
 (anonymous function) imh-all.min.js?_=1.5.305:6
 (anonymous function) imh-all.min.js?_=1.5.305:6
 INFO: Cometd Stopped
```

We're tailing the Node server log and IMH is not trying to load the page.

I have uploaded the Node project that we are using to GitHub at https://github.com/Aluman/SubscribersSearch

We abandoned the Subscriber Search Node example and instead tried using [fuel-throttle-node](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuel-throttle-node) which again works fine on localhost but we get the same error.

Any ideas or clues where we can look to next would be really helpful. Again, we are not trying to do anything unusual, we just want to get a demo app working at this stage!

Comment: What do your app center uri's look like?

Comment: If you could provide some details regarding how you are set up on your local host, that might prove helpful. All of this does indeed work, but I'm not seeing enough details to help you diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of yesterday's release this has been resolved.  Please verify that it is working for you now.

Comment: That's great news, thanks! We will test and I will confirm.

Answer (score 1):

I just spoke with an engineer on our Platform team who says there is a bug with the SSO flow in the Sandbox environment. He's creating a ticket for it and it is moving forward.

1. When you say "it works locally", do you mean:
   A: The application loads outside of the (Marketing Cloud/IMH) on your local machine?
   B: The application loads by running it locally and clicking your app's name in the App Switcher of the (Marketing Cloud/IMH)?

Comment: Hello Benjamin, thank you for confirming that there is a bug in Sandbox environment. When I said it works locally, we can visit the localhost pages on our machine: http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000/login and http://localhost:3000/logout. Sorry for not explaining in my original post, but the forum would not allow me to use the word **localhost** in my original post!

Comment: Hello Benjamin, if you could let me know once the SSO bug is fixed in Sandbox, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I've reported this to our engineers. They're working on a resolution. I'm not sure when that will be released, but will find out and report back once I'm sure.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I really appreciate this. Surely other ExactTarget integrators must be struggling with this too if no one is able to test apps on the sandbox?